# Problem with 'memoir' v3.8 and 'csquotes'

Tags: memoir, csquotes, hooks

With the latest update of `memoir` (v.3.8) I detect an error if I also load `csquotes` and defines active quotes in the following way:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeBlockQuote{<}{|}{>}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

LaTeX crashes with the following error:

> ! LaTeX hooks Error: Generic hooks cannot be added
> to '@xfloat'.

Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: You could move the csquotes command behind begin document: `\MakeBlockQuote{<}{|}{>}\EnableQuotes`. But generally it is dangerous to make chars like < and > active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not really `memoir` related. The Hook code in the kernel has issues with active chars ( `\MakeBlockQuote{<}{|}{>}` makes `>` active).

Here is a simple example that Ulrike provided elsewhere

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\test#1{?}
\AddToHook{cmd/test/after}{xx}
\catcode`\?=13
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

As Ulrike mentioned in a comment, move

```
\MakeBlockQuote{<}{|}{>}
\EnableQuotes
```

after `\begin{document}`. But in general it is a good idea to avoid making `<` and `>` active as that can cause strange results.

Apparently the Hook code does not like if the catcodes of the patch/hook was not matching the catcodes of the original definition.

The issue has been logged here: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1099